# Return Value to the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm looking for guidance on where an eventlistener returns a value in a return statement.

I found these two rules on the internet about the return statement:

1. If the return keyword is used in a function body, a value is returned (or sent) back to where function is called.
2. If the return keyword is used in an event handler, a value is returned (or sent) to the browser.

I have the following js code that is meant for a custom confirm modal that should return a true/false.  I want it tot mimic the browser's native confirm box.

In the js code below, there is a switch statement which contains an event handler.  The event handler should run the function and return true, but again I don't know where it's returning to or how to find it.  Is there a tool in the dev-tools to see this value?

```js
const dialog = {
   open (options) {
       options = Object.assign({}, {
           title: '',
           message: '',
           type: 'I',
           buttonGroup: 'okonly',
           okText: 'OK',
           cancelText: 'Cancel',
           yesText: 'Yes',
           npText: 'No',
           onok: function () {return true;},
           oncancel: function () {return false;},
           onyes: function () {return true;},
           onno: function () {return false;}
       }, options);
       
       const html = `
       <div id="dds-dialogoverlay" class="dds-dialogoverlay">
       <div id="dds-dialogbox" class="dds-dialogbox">
          <div class="dds-dialogbox__head">
            <span>Deployable Disbursing System (DDS) - ${options.title}</span>
            <button id="dds-dialogbox__close" class="dds-dialogbox__close">&times;</button>
          </div>
          <div class="dds-dialogbox__body">
             <div id="dds-dialogbox__body-left" class="dds-dialogbox__body-left"></div>
             <div id="dds-dialogbox__body-right" class="dds-dialogbox__body-right">${options.message}</div>
          </div>
          <div id="dds-dialogbox__footer" class="dds-dialogbox__footer">
             <div id="btn-groups">
                <div id="okonly-btn-group" class="btn-group">
                   <button id="okonly_ok-btn" class="t-button" type="button" value="ok">${options.okText}</button>
                </div>
                <div id="okcancel-btn-group" class="btn-group">
                   <button id="okcancel_ok-btn" class="t-button" type="button" value="ok">${options.okText}</button>
                   <button id="okcancel_cancel-btn" class="t-button" type="button" value="cancel">${options.cancelText}</button>
                </div>
                <div id="yesno-btn-group" class="btn-group">
                   <button id="yesno_yes-btn" class="t-button"  type="button" value="yes"${options.yesText}</button>
                   <button id="yesno_no-btn" class="t-button"  type="button" value="no">${options.noText}</button>
                </div>
                <div id="yesnocancel-btn-group" class="btn-group">
                   <button id="yesnocancel_yes-btn" class="t-button"  type="button" value="yes"${options.yesText}</button>
                   <button id="yesnocancel_no-btn" class="t-button"  type="button" value="no">${options.noText}</button>
                   <button id="yesnocancel_cancel-btn" class="t-button"  type="button" value="cancel">${options.cancelText}</button>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>`;

       const template = document.createElement('template');
       template.innerHTML = html;

       // Elements
       const dialogOverlay = template.content.querySelector('#dds-dialogoverlay')
       const dialogbox = template.content.querySelector('#dds-dialogbox');
       const dialogbox__head = template.content.querySelector('#dds-dialogbox__head');
       const dialogbox__body = template.content.querySelector('#dds-dialogbox__body');
       const dialogbox__footer = template.content.querySelector('#dds-dialogbox__footer');
       const dialogbox__okonlyBtnGrp = template.content.querySelector('#okonly-btn-group');
       const dialogbox__okcancelBtnGrp = template.content.querySelector('#okcancel-btn-group');
       const dialogbox__yesnoBtnGrp = template.content.querySelector('#yesno-btn-group');
       const dialogbox__yesnocancelBtnGrp = template.content.querySelector('#yesnocancel-btn-group');
       const btnClose = template.content.querySelector('.dds-dialogbox__close');
       const btnOk = template.content.querySelector('#okonly_ok-btn');
       const btnOkCancel_ok = template.content.querySelector('#okcancel_ok-btn');
       const btnOkCancel_cancel = template.content.querySelector('#okcancel_cancel-btn');
       const btnYesNo_yes = template.content.querySelector('#yesno_yes-btn');
       const btnYesNo_no = template.content.querySelector('#yesno_no-btn');
       const btnYesNoCancel_yes = template.content.querySelector('#yesnocancel_yes-btn');
       const btnYesNoCancel_no = template.content.querySelector('#yesnocancel_no-btn');
       const btnYesNoCancel_cancel = template.content.querySelector('#yesnocancel_cancel-btn');

       var dialog_type_class;

       switch (options.type) {
          case 'I':
             dialog_type_class = 'dds-dialogbox--info';
             break;
          case 'E':
            dialog_type_class = 'dds-dialogbox--error';
             break;
          case 'W':
            dialog_type_class = 'dds-dialogbox--warning';
          case 'S':
            dialog_type_class = 'dds-dialogbox--success';
       }
       dialogOverlay.classList.add('dds-dialogoverlay--show');
       dialogbox.classList.add(dialog_type_class);

       switch (options.buttonGroup) {
          case 'okonly':
             dialogbox__okonlyBtnGrp.classList.add("btn-group--show");
             btnOk.addEventListener('click', () => {
             response = options.onok();
             this._close(dialogbox, dialogOverlay);
             console.log('response is ' + response);
             return response;
           });
             break;
          case 'okcancel':
             dialogbox__okcancelBtnGrp.classList.add("btn-group--show");
             btnOkCancel_ok.addEventListener('click', () => {
               response = options.onok();
               this._close(dialogbox, dialogOverlay, response);
               
             });
             btnOkCancel_cancel.addEventListener('click', () => {
               response = options.oncancel();
               this._close(dialogbox, dialogOverlay, response);
               
             });
             break;
          case 'yesno':
             dialogbox__yesnoBtnGrp.classList.add("btn-group--show");
             btnYesNoCancel_yes.addEventListener('click', () => {
               response = options.onyes();
               this._close(dialogbox, dialogOverlay, response);
               
             });
             btnYesNo_no.addEventListener('click', () => {
               response = options.onno();
               this._close(dialogbox, dialogOverlay, response);
               
             });
             break;
          case 'yesnocancel':
            dialogbox__yesnocancelBtnGrp.classList.add("btn-group--show");
            btnYesNoCancel_yes.addEventListener('click', () => {
               response = options.onyes();
               this._close(dialogbox, dialogOverlay, response);
               
             });
            btnYesNoCancel_no.addEventListener('click', () => {
               response = options.onno();
               this._close(dialogbox, dialogOverlay, response);
               
             });
            btnYesNoCancel_cancel.addEventListener('click', () => {
               response = options.oncancel();
               this._close(dialogbox, dialogOverlay, response);
               
             });
            }

       dialogOverlay.addEventListener('click', e => {
          if (e.target === dialogOverlay) {
               options.oncancel();
               this._close(dialogbox, dialogOverlay);
          }
       })
       dialogbox.addEventListener('click', e => {
           if (e.target === dialogbox) {
               options.oncancel();
               this._close(dialogbox, dialogOverlay);
           }
       });
       
       document.body.appendChild(template.content);
   },

   _close (dialogbox, dialogOverlay) {

      dialogbox.classList.remove(dialogbox.classList.item(1));
      dialogOverlay.classList.remove("dds-dialogoverlay--show");
      document.body.removeChild(dialogOverlay);
   }
};

function Dialogbox(dialog_type = 'I', dialog_title, dialog_mess, dialog_buttons = 'okonly') {
   dialog.open({
      title: dialog_title,
      message: dialog_mess,
      type: dialog_type,
      buttonGroup: dialog_buttons
   });
}
```

Comment: [`on...` event handlers (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers): _"The return value from the handler determines if the event is canceled. The specific handling of the return value depends on the kind of event; for details, see ["The event handler processing algorithm" in the HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#the-event-handler-processing-algorithm)."_

Answer (score 0):

EventListener's callback returns nothing to browsers. if you have return statement inside the event handler, it just stops execution of eventhandler there. For more detailing you may go through the URL : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback

Comment: Then I guess a better question would be what's the best way to return the true/false in a custom dialog box

Comment: Yes that"s true. My answer was mostly tp clear idea regarding return value of event listener. Hope that  is clear now.

Comment: The event listener/handler is clear, the ability to return true/false in the scenario above is not.  Do I need to revamp the code about to return the true/false better? How to return the true/false value